# Jackson deserializer fallback based on value

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Is it possible to create a Jackson deserializer that is "chained" with others. For instance, we have a generalized, custom deserializer for Enumerations that handles a special case, but we'd like to fallback to the default Jackson implementation if the custom deserializer fails to handle the incoming Enumeration.

It seems as if there's no simple way to do this on a *value* basis - I've seen examples on something similar on the *type* level, however.

The issue seems to stem from the fact that registering a deserializer for a specific class gives that deserializer precedence over any others that are registered and thus the previously registered deserializer is lost. There doesn't seem to be a concept of chaining built-in, so returning null from the custom deserializer doesn't pass the value down the chain of registered deserializers for that type.

Any insight on how to get deserializers to chain would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
Here's an example of the intended behavior vs. the (simplified) current setup.

The current setup:

```
object EnumSerializerModule extends JacksonModule {
  override def getModuleName: String = "permissive-enums"

  this += { _.addDeserializers(PermissiveEnumDeserializerLocator) }
}

object PermissiveEnumDeserializerLocator extends Deserializers.Base {
  override def findEnumDeserializer(javaType: Class[_], config: DeserializationConfig, desc: BeanDescription): JsonDeserializer[_] = {
    new PermissiveEnumDeserializer(javaType.asInstanceOf[Class[Enum[_ <: Enum[_]]]])
  }
}

// Super simplified version of a custom enum deserializer
class PermissiveEnumDeserializer(javaType: Class[Enum[_ <: Enum[_]]]) extends StdScalarDeserializer[Enum[_ <: Enum[_]]](javaType) {
  override def deserialize(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Enum[_ <: Enum[_]] = {
    val enumConstants = javaType.getEnumConstants

    // Attempt string representation
    val constant: Enum[_ <: Enum[_]] = val fromStringRep = enumConstants.find(_.toString.equalsIgnoreCase(text)).orNull

    if (constant != null) {
      return constant
    }

    throw ctxt.mappingException(jp.getText + " was not one of " + enumConstants.map(_.name).mkString("[", ", ", "]"))
  }
}
```

In this example, the deserializer would fail on an Enum that is serialized using its "name" value, rather than its "toString" (which might be overridden). Ideally, I'd like for this custom setup to delegate to any *previously* bounded deserializers on the object mapper to handle the value.

So... in pseudocode:

```
val originalJacksonDeser = new EnumDeserializer
val customDeser = new PermissiveEnumDeserializer
val enumValue = MySpecialEnum.ONE

var res = customDeser(enumValue)
if (res == null) {
  res = originalJacksonDeser(enumValue)

return res
```

Comment: I got some ideas but you need to provide an example of what you expect since it's not completely clear to justify an implementation attempt.

Comment: @Black.Jack totally - will update with an example.